# Find the reflection point $P$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, coloring

On the real number line, paint red all points that correspond to points of the form $81x+100y$, where $x$ and $y$ are positive integers. Paint the remaining integer points blue. Find a point $P$ on the line such that, for every integer point $T$, the reflection of $T$ w.r.t. $P$ is an integer point with a different colour than $T$.

> With a great deal of difficulty, I was able to prove that the largest number that cannot be written as $81x+100y$ is $7919$. However, I can't go any further.
>   Please Help!
>   Thanks!

Comment: You could note that the smallest red integer is $181$.  So this and $7919$ need to be each other's reflection, giving you the function for reflection.